# The atmosphere's water vapour capacity

Tags: atmospheric-science

If enough energy was supplied, could all liquid water on Earth evaporate into the atmosphere? Could the atmosphere hold this much water vapour? Would the pressure and density increase as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Atmospheric pressure is 14.7 lb/sq inch. That is, the air in a 1 inch square column from the ground to outer space weighs 14.7 lb.

A 1 inch square column of water 32 feet tall also weighs 14.7 lb. A column as deep as the ocean weighs tons. This means there is several hundred times more water than atmosphere.

If you heated the ocean until it boiled, you would get an atmosphere of almost all water vapor. The pressure at the bottom would increase. When the pressure gets high enough, water doesn't boil. It stays liquid, even when very hot.

This happens at the bottom of the ocean. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent